# Using EFFECTIVE_TS and EXPIRATION_TS on FACT tables

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I have a requirement to create a Fact table which stores granted_share_qty awarded to employees. There are surrounding Dimensions like SPS Grant_dim which stores info about each grant, SPS Plan Dim which stores info about the Plan, SPS Client Dim which stores info about the Employer and SPS Customer Dim which stores info about the customer. The DimKeys (Surrogate Key) and DurableKeys(Supernatural Keys) from each Dimension is added to the Fact.

Reporting need is "as-of" ie on any given date, one should be able to see the granted_share_qty as of that date (similar to account balance as of that date) along with point-in-time values of few attributes from the Grant,Plan, Client, Customer dimensions.

First, we thought of creating a daily snapshot table where the data is repeated everyday in the fact (unless source sends any changes). However since there could be more than 100 million grant records , repeating this everyday was almost impossible, moreover the granted_share_qty doesnt change that often so why copy this everyday?.

So instead of a daily snapshot we thought of adding an EFFECTIVE_DT and EXPIRATION_DT on the Fact table (like a TIMESPAN PERIODIC SNAPSHOT table if such a thing exists)
[image]

This reduces the volume and perfectly satisfies a reporting need like "get me the granted_qty and grant details,client, plan, customer details as of 10/01/2022 " will translate to  *"select granted_qty from fact where 10/01/2022 between EFFECTIVE_DT and EXPIRATION_DT and Fact.DimKeys=Dim.DimKeys"*

The challenge however is to keep the Dim Keys of the Fact in sync with Dim Keys of the Dimensions. Even if the Fact doesn't change, any DimKey changes due to versioning in any of the Dimension need to be tracked and versioned in the Fact. This has become an implementation nightmare

(To worsen the things, the Dims could undergo multiple intraday changes , so these are to be tracked near-real-time :-( )

Any thoughts how to handle such situations will be highly appreciated (Database: Snowflake)
P:S: We could remove the DimKeys from the Fact and use DurableKeys+Date to join between the Facts and Type 2 Dims, but that proposal is not favored/approved as of now

Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

> First, we thought of creating a daily snapshot table where the data is repeated everyday in the fact (unless source sends any changes). However

Stop right there.  Whenever you know the right model but think it's un-workable for some reason, try harder.  At a minimum test your assumption that it would be "too much data", and consider not materializing the snapshot but leaving it as a view and computing it at query time.

> ... moreover the granted_share_qty doesnt change that often so why copy this everyday?.

And there's your answer.  Use a monthly snapshot instead of a daily snapshot, and you've divided the data by 30.